# Is it possible to curve fit a function that has multiple inputs?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm trying to curve fit a 3d function in Matlab that requires an input of X and Y values (they must be generated in a meshgrid first). I'm using the lsqcurvefit() function in Matlab, but from my understanding of the documentation is assumes the function that it's curve fitting the provided data to only takes one input argument.

The function to be fitted has a declaration like the following:

```
function y = dog2DFunction(params, inputX, inputY)
```

The independent variables are generated like so:

```
[xVals, yVals] = meshgrid(-res/2:1:res/2-1);
```

And then the call to finally curve fit the data 'Z' to the function is the following:

```
fittedVals2 = lsqcurvefit(@dog2DFunction, guess, xVals, yVals, Z);
```

But I'm getting an error in the "dog2DFunction" that says there aren't enough input arguments which tells me that lsqcurvefit isn't passing in yVals.

Is there a way to pass in two independent variables into the lsqcurvefit function? I tried flattening xVals and yVals and then passing it in as one large flat vector and then resizing it in the "dog2DFunction" function, but lsqCurve fit requires the input to be of equal length to the data to be fitted (in this case, 'Z').

Any ideas?

EDIT: I found a solution!

1) Pass the function into lsqcurvefit like so:

```
fittedVals2 = lsqcurvefit(@dog2DFunction, guess, [flatten(xVals); flatten(yVals)], flatten(Z));
```

2) In the function being used to curve fit, add these lines so that a) the function works as a standalone given some x and y input and b) when called on by lsqcurve fit, accommodate for its restriction that only allows an x input:

```
function y = dog2DFunction(params, inputX, inputY)
    if ~exist('inputY','var')
        inputY = inputX(2,:);
        inputX = inputX(1,:);
    end
...
end
```

Comment: Did you try `cftool`? It is possible to specify an arbitrary number of inputs there.

Comment: Well the issue is that I need to fit my data points to a function (a Difference of Gaussians) so that I can pull out values like xStandard Deviation, yStandard Deviation, etc.)

Comment: @ChristianGonzalez If you found a solution, consider writing an answer instead of editing it into your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new at this!